# Attach a moved file to its previous history afterwards

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

Due to a [defect in the MercurialEclipse](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/77/renaming-of-a-file-brokes-the-history) plugin, I have lost the history of a moved file.

It's been  while now, and I have switched to a newer version of MercurialEclipse which fixes this bug.

I would like to connect this file to its previous location/versions.

How can I achieve that ?
Either in Eclipse or with command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create clean "move changeset" in anonymous branch and `graft` it into needed location?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to find out all the history of a specific files, both before/after rename/move/copy, a simple "hg log --follow filename" will do that.

```
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg$ hg init test
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg$ cd test
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ echo a > a.txt
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg add a.txt
adding a.txt
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg ci -m a.txt
a.txt
committed changeset 0:552282c32ac4
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg mv a.txt b.txt
moving a.txt to b.txt
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg ci -m "a.txt-->b.txt"
b.txt
committed changeset 1:10dda3a3b48a
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg mv b.txt c.txt
moving b.txt to c.txt
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg ci -m "b.txt-->c.txt"
c.txt
committed changeset 2:f79245e6c0fe
luke@luke-linux:~/work/hg/test$ hg log --follow c.txt
changeset:   2:f79245e6c0fe
tag:         tip
user:        Luke Luo <luke.jf.luo@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Nov 21 23:23:16 2012 +0800
files:       b.txt c.txt
description:
b.txt-->c.txt


changeset:   1:10dda3a3b48a
user:        Luke Luo <luke.jf.luo@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Nov 21 23:22:56 2012 +0800
files:       a.txt b.txt
description:
a.txt-->b.txt


changeset:   0:552282c32ac4
user:        Luke Luo <luke.jf.luo@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Nov 21 23:22:34 2012 +0800
files:       a.txt
description:
a.txt
```

Comment: NO `hg move` in OP trouble happened